# Fitting a multivariable polynomial with inequality constraints on the polynomial

Tags: optimization, scipy, regression, curve-fitting, inequality

I have experimental scattered data (in green, in the picture) in a 2D domain (x,y), that I want to fit with a two-dimensional polynomial, such as:

- **f(x,y) = c0 + c1*x + c2*y + c3*x*y + c4 * x ** 2 * y ** 2**

where c0, c1,... are the coefficients of the polynomial. On top of this, I have equality and inequality constraints:

- **f(x=0,y) = 0**
- **f(x,y) > 0, for 0 < x < 90**

How can I do this? Can I express my inequality in f(x,y), by inequalities in the c0, c1, c2,... coefficients?

I used `scipy.optimize.minimize` to minimize the least squares of **||Ax-B||**, where **Ax** is the polynomial expression evaluated at the experimental points, **x** is the vector of the coefficients c0, c1, c2,... to be optimized, and **B** is my experimental data. I really need some guidance on how to apply the inequality constraint.

What I tried so far:

- I was able to implement the equality constraint, manually simplifying f(x,y) and f(x=0,y)=0, by substitution, and reformulating ||Ax-B||, but I cannot do that for the inequality constraint. See the picture,
  where f(x=0,y) = 0 is satisfied, but not f(x,y) > 0.
- I tried using the `constraints` parameter, but I could only apply inequality constraints on the c0,c1,c2,... coefficients, instead of applying the constraint on the desired f(x,y).
- I have read on Lagrange multipliers and non-linear programming but I'm still lost.

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions:

- With `scipy.optimize.minimize` the function to be minimized is some kind of chi^2, but additionally, it your constraints are not met, then it returns `np.inf`, which provides hard boundary.
- Use Monte-Carlo Markov Chain method. There are many implementations in python.

Comment: It is an interesting way of going around the problem. But since I'm interested in academic publishing, I should first be sure that this can or cannot be solved mathematically. Another downside to your suggestion is that such a function (returning np.inf if conditions are not met) would not be differentiable.

Comment: "But since I'm interested in academic publishing, I should first be sure that this can or cannot be solved mathematically." - That's something I don't get. Do you mean that my solution is called other than "mathematical"? Maybe "algorithmic"? Your sentence suggests that usage of computers in science is banned if possible. I strongly disagree with that. And yes, the function is not differentiable, but you have not required that.

Comment: BTW, it's not mine approach that makes the function to be optimized not differentiable; it's your constraints that require it.

Comment: I was not able to perform your first solution. The optimization algorithm cannot find the right path when it constantly gets np.inf. I made it work as a soft boundary, where I penalize the algorithm proportionally to how negative f(x,y) is, but this too gave problems before being fine tuned, so it is far from a general solution to all my fitting cases (I have several).
I do not understand your second solution.
I do thank you and upvoted you for your contribution, the best so far.

Comment: MCMC is used for sampling distributions. You can use it to sample distribution of c0-c4.